# chef gem_package not using the right binary

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to install the gems "sensu_plugin" and "mixlib-shellout", on a windows server 2008r2, from a recipe. In this last one, I have the following code :

```
%w{ sensu-plugin mixlib-shellout }.each do |gem_plugin|
  gem_package gem_plugin do
    gem_binary("C:/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem")
    options("--no-rdoc --no-ri")
    action :install
  end
end
```

Yet, when running the recipe on my machine, I receive the error "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT) No such file or directory - U:/". What I found out is that whenever I try installing a gem package using the gem binary located in the chef-client directory (C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\gem), it raised this last error.

The thing is that the gem I wish to use to installed the gem packages is actually located in C:/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem, which I have declared in the gem_binary option.

In the end it looks like chef is ignoring the gem_binary option and trying to install it from its own gem binary.

I can't see what's wrong with this config. Is the gem_binary really indicating what binary to use?

Comment: I found out that this code block is working fine on a windows machine with only one disk, C:/. Yet, the problems happens on some other machines where the HOMEDRIVE is on another disk (network disk) U:/. Yet, I can't understand why it won't work.

Comment: as per the docs https://docs.chef.io/resource_gem_package.html it looks like you want to set `source 'c:/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem` ` and `clear_sources true`. If this works for you I can turn it into an answer, but I don't have the ability to test your case.